# Is it possible to have a trailing period in user.name in Git?

Tags: git

The following Git statement

```
cd periodtest/
git init
git config user.name "Test."

# verify that user.name is 'Test.'
git config user.name

touch README
git add README
git commit -a -m "period test"
```

Results in the following checkout

```
# check user name after commit
git log 
And the resulting commit w/out the period was:
commit 9b7e4960fd8129059b5759d1bb937b60241fd70b
Author: Test <email@test.com>
Date:   Wed Oct 1 20:28:28 2014 -0700

    period test
```

Is there a way to get that period to stay in the username?

Comment: At least 1.9.3 shows this behaviour. Strange.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behaviour is hardcoded into git.

***Edit**: As it stands this is still true for git version 2.25.1 (27. February 2020)*.

To create the *author* string during a commit git removes *crud* (as git calls it) from the beginning and the end of the string. For this it uses the `strbuf_addstr_without_crud` function defined in `ident.c` - [see ident.c line 426 version 2.25.1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.25.1/ident.c#L426).

Take a look at the function header:

```c
/*
 * Copy over a string to the destination, but avoid special
 * characters ('\n', '<' and '>') and remove crud at the end
 */
static void strbuf_addstr_without_crud(struct strbuf *sb, const char *src)
```

[See ident.c lines 225-262 version 2.25.1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.25.1/ident.c#L225-L262).

Git determines *crud* via another function which checks for specific characters.

```c
static int crud(unsigned char c)
{
  return  c <= 32  ||
    c == '.' ||
    c == ',' ||
    c == ':' ||
    c == ';' ||
    c == '<' ||
    c == '>' ||
    c == '"' ||
    c == '\\' ||
    c == '\'';
}
```

[See ident.c lines 198-210 version 2.25.1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.25.1/ident.c#L198-L210).

As you can see a period is considered *crud* by git and will be removed, at the moment there is no flag or option you can set to avoid this behaviour.

---

This means you have two options.

1. You fork git and change the way git creates the *author* string.
2. Or you append another character after the trailing period, for example a [Zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (which often won't be printed properly on a console)

Alternatively you can always submit a feature request on the git mailing list, but in this case I wouldn't raise my hopes too high.

Comment: `git config --get user.name` confirms this : the dot is actually present in the config string, just not used at commit execution, as you explained.

Comment: I tried the zero width space but this wouldn't allow it being pushed to BitBucket when ControlFreak is in charge. So I have the problem that I cannot push without zero-width space as the trailing period gets removed; and not with the zero-width space as this obviously gets converted to a trailing space when pushing so ControlFreak stops for this reason...

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023): it now excludes "`.`" from the set of characters to be removed from the beginning and the end of the human-readable name.

See [commit 1c04cb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c04cb0744d2acdcaebc77b0e78c47efbba67fd5) (02 Aug 2023) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cf07e53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf07e53bae8492fc6ee8a8d394e2fba858daa0a4), 09 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ident`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c04cb0744d2acdcaebc77b0e78c47efbba67fd5): don't consider '`.`' a crud
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> When we process a user's name (as in user.name), we strip all leading and trailing crud from it.
> Right now, we consider a dot a crud character, and strip it off.
>
> However, this is unsuitable for many personal names because humans frequently have abbreviated suffixes, such as "`Jr.`" or "`Sr.`" at the end of their names, and this corrupts them.
> Some other users may wish to use an abbreviated name or initial, which will pose a problem especially in cultures that write the family name first, followed by the personal name.
>
> Since the current approach causes lots of practical problems, let's avoid it by no longer considering a dot to be crud.
>
> Note that "`.`" in the name forces the entire name to be quoted to please mailers, but stripping "`.`" only at the beginning and the end does not help a name with "`.`" in the middle (like "`brian m. carlson`") so this change will not make it much worse.
> A name like "`Given Family, Jr.`" that did not have to be quoted now would need to be, in order to be placed on the e-mail headers, though.
>
> This is based on a [weather-balloon patch by Jeff King sent in Aug 2021](https://lore.kernel.org/git/YSKm8Q8nyTavQaox@coredump.intra.peff.net/)

Answer (score 0):

While you can’t specify a trailing period in `git commit`, you can add it post factum using `git filter-repo`. For example, this command will append a period to the last commit’s author name:

```bash
git filter-repo --refs HEAD^.. --name-callback 'return name + b"."'
```

NB: in general, filter-repo comes with some caveats but is very powerful if you use it right. This particular command limits the rewrite to the last commit using `--refs`, but you can also have it apply the changes throughout the repository’s whole history or for a particular branch all the way back to the root. The man page lists some [limitations](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_limitations); notably, affected signed tags will become unsigned.

In older versions of Git where filter-repo is unavailable, you can probably use `git filter-branch` to a similar effect.